# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment when trying to setView

Tags: android, fragment, findviewbyid, setcontentview

it says IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment when I'm trying to setview.I know problem lies at 3rd and 4th line. it's News.java file news is a fragment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_news);
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: atleast post the related code and the exception. You are talking about fragment but posted code of activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment.java file is look like below code :

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        //ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

       init(view);

        return view;
    }
```

after that in `init` method type below code:

```
private void init(View view){

listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

**also u don't forgot to `extends Fragment`**

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked but it's returning blank fragment. I followed this tutorial  https://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/  and implemented it on fragment instead of activity purposefully. now I don't know what do i need to do to get that feed. currently, it's returning an empty feed. with nothing in it.

Comment: which link u can follow for this

Comment: I've added link and some information and thank you so much for your help